# Spring boot application redirect behind reverse proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, proxy, reverse

So I'm trying to set up a spring boot application behind a reverse proxy, but when I use `HttpServletResponse.redirect("/")` it always redirects to the internal url. This happens with and without `use-forward-headers: true`.

The headers I'm getting from the reverse proxy are following:

```
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
forwarded: for=10.x.x.x;host=internal-domain.com;proto=http
x-forwarded-server: external-domain.com
host: internal-domain.com
x-forwarded-host: internal-domain.com
x-forwarded-port: 80
x-forwarded-proto: http
```

I can't change what the reverse proxy returns.

If anyone could help, that would be awesome :)
Thanks

Comment: Probably not the 'correct' way, but can you return redirect headers manually with the fqdn grabbed from the `x-forwarded-server` header ?

Comment: Well, the problem is that I'm using `spring-security-saml2-core` and this uses the redirect behind the scenes, so I don't think I'm able to do this.
I could fire up another docker container with another reverse proxy that returns the external url as Host header.
Another solution would be to intercept all requests in java but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You found a solution for this?

Comment: @SysHex i’m not sure what my solution was